# .NET Core React SPA - expected behavior when unauthorized user visits <AuthorizeRoute>?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, .net-core, single-page-application, identityserver4

My app requires the user to be authenticated before viewing any pages, so I've wrapped the content of all pages within the `<AuthorizeRoute>` component that's part of .NET Core's [authentication for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

When I start the app locally in Visual Studio, the user is redirected to the login page as expected. If I preserve console logs, I see:

`AuthorizeService.js:51 Silent authentication error:  ErrorResponse: login_required`

It's plain white text (not red like a `console.error()` message). After this is the notice that the browser navigated to the login page `Navigated to https://localhost:44398/Identity/Account/Login?...`

At this point, the user can log in and visit internal pages, and there are no issues with how the app functions.

Recently I noticed information in Visual Studio's debug output about an `Error` just after app startup:

```
"Error": "login_required",
"Category": "Token",
"Name": "Token Issued Failure",
"EventType": "Failure"
```

The app does not crash with an unhandled exception, there's no stack trace, and it appears that the error could have been thrown to indicate the user was not authenticated and the original action was cancelled. The `Error` appears to be handled by the app, and the user is redirected to the login page.
***Is this the expected behavior or do I still have a hidden bug to fix that will bite me?***

The debug output also shows many subsequent exceptions thrown such as `System.OperationCanceledException`, which all seem related to cancelling the original page view and recovering.

Thanks for any help, I've begun to wonder if I've been chasing a mere ghost!

I've included more debug output below for reference:

```
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\SC\Desktop\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\bin\Debug\netcoreapp5.0\IdentityModel.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Security.Principal.dll'. 
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator: Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator: Information: Changing response to LoginRequired: prompt=none was requested
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Information: {
  "ClientId": "ProjectManager",
  "ClientName": "ProjectManager",
  "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44398/authentication/login-callback",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "/authentication/login-callback"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "RequestedScopes": "ProjectManagerAPI openid profile",
  "State": "3bf3c9ae34d047e388fa7378fej036c",
  "PromptMode": "none",
  "SessionId": "",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "ProjectManager",
    "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44398/authentication/login-callback",
    "response_type": "code",
    "scope": "ProjectManagerAPI openid profile",
    "state": "3bf3c9ae34d047e388fa7abbab96036c",
    "code_challenge": "tcAR0R0szm4IAIxD390902vGBivzUvTp1aJHvVI",
    "code_challenge_method": "S256",
    "prompt": "none",
    "response_mode": "query"
  }
}
IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService: Information: {
  "ClientId": "ProjectManager",
  "ClientName": "ProjectManager",
  "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44398/authentication/login-callback",
  "Endpoint": "Authorize",
  "Scopes": "ProjectManagerAPI openid profile",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "Error": "login_required",
  "Category": "Token",
  "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
  "EventType": "Failure",
  "Id": 2001,
  "ActivityId": "80000035-0002-fe00-b63f-847sdu473bb",
  "TimeStamp": "2021-02-26T00:58:11Z",
  "ProcessId": 16392,
  "LocalIpAddress": "::1:44398",
  "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
}
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator: Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.3\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.IO.Pipelines.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Net.WebSockets.dll
The thread 0x1794 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Not sure if you ever got anywhere with this, but we're seeing the same thing. Possibly chasing the same ghost as you...

Comment: Hi johnbt, Eventaully I came to the conclusion that this was the expected behavior, but am not 100% sure I'm correct.  When I move it to Azure production, that's when I tend to be alerted to issues that weren't stopping the show locally, but sometimes are in production.  It's a side project for me, so not a big deal if I move it to production and have to do some troubheshooting then.  Thanks for your feedback.